# Azure Storage: Blob vs. Tables

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, azure-storage

I have three groups of data for 5,000 famous artworks:

1. Jpeg Images
2. Wikipedia Snippets (approx. 350 characters) of some but not all artworks
3. Artwork Info e.g. Title, Artist, Gallery etc.

The images are in **Blob Storage**. Currently I am also storing the Wikipedia Snippets and Artwork Info in Blob Storage. These are both stored in **XML format** and are accessed via an integer ID for each Artwork.

This is part of a Windows Phone 8.1 app where the Lock Screen & Live Tile can update daily or hourly for users. My question is, in terms of performance, am I better off moving the Wikipedia and Art Info from Blob Storage to Table storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your metadata information (such as Snippets and Artwork) in Azure Table. You will need to design your Table schema in such a way that you can use point query. A Point Query is the most efficient lookup to use and is recommended to be used for high-volume lookups or lookups requiring lowest latency. Such a query can use the indexes to locate an individual entity very efficiently by specifying both the PartitionKey and RowKey values. For example: $filter=(PartitionKey eq 'Sales') and (RowKey eq '2') (See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/) for more information.

I recommend running some test to compare the results since the performance will vary depending on type of query that you use.

Thanks,
Aung